# Laravel schema builder converts tablename to lowercase

Tags: php, laravel-5, naming-conventions

I'm just wondering why the schema builder in laravel automatically convert all camel case to lower case in table naming

E.g

```
Schema::create('myTable', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        ....
    });
```

It creates tablename: mytable

Why is that? Is that a convention of laravel? I don't see it in the laravel docs Schema Builder page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a common practice to use snake case in table names and field names as well and it's not only related to laravel but most people follow this convention. In `Laravel`'s old (4x) documentation, it's been mentioned that:

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our User
>   model. The **lower-case**, plural name of the class will be used as the
>   table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this
>   case, Eloquent will assume the User model stores records in the users
>   table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on
>   your model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

}
```

So, yes, `Laravel` uses `strtolower` function in many places and probably this is better to follow the common convention and it's (`my_table`) known as `snake case`.